# Visio drawing control AccessViolationException on adding a shape

Tags: c#, com, access-violation, visio

I have a form with a `Visio Drawing Control` placed on it. I am using `Visio Drawing Control 11.0` (Visio 2003 is installed on my PC). On the form load event, I do the following:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.axDrawingControl1.Src = @"D:\visio test\drawing.vsd";
    Document currentStencil = this.axDrawingControl1.Document.Application.Documents.OpenEx(@"Basic_U.vss", (short)VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);
    Window stencilWindow = this.axDrawingControl1.Document.OpenStencilWindow();
}
```

When I run the application, I add a shape to the document and then the application crashes with the `AccessViolationException.` The error message says `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`
However, when I do *NOT* open a document by setting the `DrawingControl.Src` property to document's filename, the application works fine, but I *need* to open a document and edit it using the drawing control.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to wait until the document is fully loaded.

Add an event handler for this.axDrawingControl1.DocumentOpened and move your drawing code to that handler.

Comment: The problem was solved by rebooting my PC, hehe. Thank you anyway.